# Improving play template with javascript code

Tags: jquery, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a play-template with javascript code in it. Everything works but it has two disadvantages:

- Bad readability with eclipse-play-plugin, javascript is not colored in code highlighting
- I can't use the jquery-document-ready functionality because (I think) the jquery stuff is not yet loaded at this point of the dom tree. So I had to take the *native* implementation with `setInterval()`

On the other hand, the advantage I have with his solution is:

- I can use the play-scala-template stuff to generate javascript code
- all the code is together in one file and not somehow lost in the `public/javascript` folder

Any suggestion to improve the code is welcome! Thanks

```
@(categories: List[WikiCategory])

@import play.i18n._
@import helper._

@main(Messages.get("frontend.wiki.title")) {

<form class="form-search">
    <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="@Messages.get("frontend.wiki.search.placeholder")" id="searchInput"></input>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton" onclick="search()">@Messages.get("frontend.wiki.search")</button>
</form>

@* most read articles *@
<div class="row">
    @components.wikitable(Messages.get("frontend.wiki.mostread"), WikiArticle.findAllMostReadArticles(5), 999)
</div>

@* articles by category *@
@for((category, i) <- categories.zipWithIndex) {
    @if(i%2 == 0) { <div class="row"> }
        <div class="span6">
            @components.wikitable(category.name, WikiArticle.findAllByCategory(category, 5), category.id)
        </div>
    @if(i%2 == 1) { </div> }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var search = function() {
            var input = $('#searchInput').val();
            $.post( "/wiki/search/" + escape(input), function( data ) {
                console.log("found in table999 " + data.length + " articles for criteria " + input); 
                $('#table999').empty();
                $('#table999').append($(template(data)));
            });

            @for((category, i) <- categories.zipWithIndex) {
                $.post( "/wiki/search/@category.id/" + escape(input), function( data ) {
                    console.log("found in table@category.id " + data.length + " articles for criteria " + input); 
                    $('#table@category.id').empty();
                    $('#table@category.id').append($(template(data)));
                });
            }
    }
    var template = function(articles) {
        var table = "";
        for (var i = 0, limit = articles.length; i < limit; i++) {
            table += article(articles[i]);
        }
        return table;
    }
    var shortArticleText = function(text) {
        var lengthText = 80
        if (text.length > lengthText)
            return text.substring(0, lengthText) + "..."
        else
            return text
    }
    var article = function(article) {
        var row = "<tr><td><a href=\"/wikiarticle/" + article.id + "\" class=\"btn btn-primary\">" + article.title + "</a>&nbsp;</td>";
        row += "<td>" + shortArticleText(article.text) + "</td></tr>";
        return row;
    }
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            search();
            clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
        }
    }, 10);
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way for correct implementation JS is ... checking the HTML code in the browser, most probably you are including jQuery at the end of doc, therefore it's not available. Create  stable HTML file and work on JS there, when you'll debug and finish it then move it to the view (place parts in proper places).

Also consider moving JS scripts into separate `.js` file .